# Bootstrap 3 Menu, one button that toggles the tab and opens a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting together a menu for a bootstrap website, learning this as I go but I'm lost in the world of javascript now.

Just say we have a tabbed nav menu typical to boostrap, when the tab is clicked it becomes active, and it also activates a drop down menu. I can get it to do one of either but not both.

Demo here

http://www.bootply.com/120851

Basically when "pane2" is clicked the dropdown should appear in pane2 content area.
I have included the link to toggle the dropdown separate from the menu just so you can see it works when "pane2" is selected/active. I hope I make sense here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/121226

Gone down a different road for the same effect with onclick link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code int pane2

```
<div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="tab-pane">   
   <div class="the-window">
    <div class="dropDownTab">
      <div class="taglist">do stuff</div>
      <div class="taglist">do stuff</div>
      <div class="taglist">do stuff</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

and following css:

```
.dropDownTab {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: 48px;
    width: 72px;
    text-align: center;
}
```